# BlueJ: Create object via codepad that'll appear in Object Bench?

Tags: java, object, bluej

I'm a complete beginner at programming and am starting off with Java in BlueJ.
I was trying to create a new object by typing a code line like:

```
ClassName ClassName1 = new ClassName();
```

Which indeed does create a new object but the newly created object does not appear in Object Bench.
It seems to be running in the background somewhere.

Whereas it would appear in Object Bench, if I create a new object via right-click on the class.

But is there a way to create new object so that it also does via code?

Answer (score 0):

The object bench is more for experimentation than for the actual program. They are used to pick apart each object and see how each method functions.

You are not able to add objects from the Java library, but this is possible if you use the BlueJ API, since you can use the addToBench method from BObject. But otherwise, there is no way to do this from the methods give through the Java API.

Comment: Hey! Thanks very much! I just tried to do what you recommended doing to me but I am a real beginner...I have the class called "Notebook" and tried to create an object of this class by typing on the codepad: "addToBench(notebook1)" but then I get an error message "Error: cannot find symbol -   method addToBench(Notebook)" ...Sorry, but I am really new at coding...

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to do that:

You can create the object in the codepad, as you describe. The result object will be shown as a small red object next to the line of code that displays the result. You can drag this small object onto the object bench.

Alternatively, you can use the 'Use Library Class...' function from the Tools menu to create an object from a Java library class and place it onto the object bench.

Answer (score 0):

For BlueJ 4.1.2
As explained in BlueJ's Help -> Interactive tutorial 
(takes 15 mins and worth a glance)

> The codepad accepts statements (with a semi-colon at the end, which
>   return no value), or expressions (without a semi-colon, which return a
>   value).

**statement is an expression that ends with a semicolon**

*In other words mutators (statements) need a semicolon at the end, while accessors (expressions) do not.*

e.g.

```
new ClassName()  // is an expression
new ClassName(); // is a statement
```

Note that is very important to understand the quoted part upstairs (**expression Vs statement**) to take advantage of the codepad correct use

In your example you have three options:

1. write in Code pad(note without a semicolon because we're interested in the value --actually a reference to a ClassName object [or instance if you prefer]-- returned from the expression):

> `new ClassName()`

2. write in Code pad the statement and then call the reference variable(without semicolon)

> ```
> ClassName className1 = new ClassName();
> className1
> ```

3. write in Code pad only the statement

> ```
> ClassName className1 = new ClassName();
> ```

in 1. and 2. cases :

> You'll see a result line appear, with a tiny red object icon on the
>   left side. If you hover over the red box, you'll see an arrow appear
>   indicating that if you click, the result will be added to the object
>   bench. Click, and you'll be asked for an object name. Leave it as
>   is(e.g. *className1*) and click OK.
>
> Now that *className1* is on the object bench, we can use it(invoke his
>   methods) in the codepad. E.g. write the lines below in the
>   codepad(substitute method and arg with your actual methods and
>   arguments) and press Enter:

```
className1.accessorMethod1()
className1.mutatorMethod2(arg1, arg2);
etc
```

***Pay attention to not forget the final semicolon on mutator methods and conversely not put it in accessor methods***

in case 3.

> You'll see no result line appear, with a tiny red object icon on the
>   left side. 
>   So you cannot use the object bench and have to work only with code pad